# Calling an API that runs on another GCP project with Airflow Composer

Tags: api, http, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm running a task with `SimpleHTTPOperator` on `Airflow Composer`. This task calls an API that runs on `Cloud Run Service` living in another project. This means I need a service account in order to access the project.

When I try to make a call to the api, I get the following error :

```
{secret_manager_client.py:88} ERROR - Google Cloud API Call Error (PermissionDenied): No access for Secret ID airflow-connections-call_to_api.
            Did you add 'secretmanager.versions.access' permission?
```

What's a solution to such an issue ?

> **Context** : Cloud Composer and Cloud Run live in 2 different Projects

Comment: Which service account is using your Cloud composer ?
I think you have to give the 'secretmanager.versions.access' permission to the Composer Service account on the 2nd project (where the Cloud Run Service is running).

Comment: Facing the same issue. Is there a resolution to this?

Answer (score 0):

This specific error is irrelevant to the cross project scenario. It seems that you have configured Composer/Airflow to use Secret Manager as the primary backend for connections and variables. However, according to the error message , the service account used by Composer is missing the `secretmanager.versions.access` permission to access the connection (call_to_api) you have configured for the API.

Check [this part](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/secret-manager#configure_access_control) of the documentation.

Comment: Access is already granted to the service account from which the composer environment is running.

Comment: @Ashwin in Snowfire's issue it was clear from the log message that this wasn't the case. Please submit a separate question.